# SOIL not displaying the images

Tags: c++, opengl, soil

I have a problem with SOIL in C++. The problem is when i try to load am image from a path given, it only show white.

First i load it into the memory as follows:

```
_t = SOIL_load_OGL_texture(_texture.c_str(),
                        SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
                        SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID,
                        SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y);
```

Afterwards i use it like this:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _t);

glPushMatrix();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f (0, 0); glVertex3f(-1 + (_p.X)/(App::WinSize().X / 2), 1 - (_p.Y)/(App::WinSize().Y / 2), 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f (1, 0); glVertex3f(-1 + (_p.X + _s.X)/(App::WinSize().X / 2), 1 - (_p.Y)/(App::WinSize().Y / 2), 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f (1, 1); glVertex3f(-1 + (_p.X + _s.X)/(App::WinSize().X / 2), 1 - (_p.Y + _s.Y)/(App::WinSize().Y / 2), 0.0f);
    glTexCoord2f (0, 1); glVertex3f(-1 + (_p.X)/(App::WinSize().X / 2), 1 - (_p.Y + _s.Y)/(App::WinSize().Y / 2), 0.0f);
glEnd();

glPopMatrix();
```

I use Visual Studio 2012. I placed the folder with the images in the folder where the .exe file ends when it is being debugged.

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but here is the OpenGL setup the program runs when it is being executed:

```
glutInit(&argc, &argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_MULTISAMPLE | GLUT_BORDERLESS);
glEnable(GLUT_MULTISAMPLE);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, size.X, 0.0, size.Y, -1.0, 1.0);
glutInitWindowPosition(position.X, position.Y);
glutInitWindowSize(size.X, size.Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking for error during the loading process?

Add

```
/* check for an error during the load process */
if( 0 == _t )
{
    printf( "SOIL loading error: '%s'\n", SOIL_last_result() );
}
```

right after you load the texture using `SOIL_load_OGL_texture` to check if your texture has been loaded without any errors.

Comment: @Stef: Are you using the relative path to the images?

Comment: I should be using the correct path. The .exe is in the debug folder. With it i put the folder named TestImages. The path i then use is:
    "TestImages/CrossNoMouse.png"